# Commutative diagrams for vector spaces, dual spaces, and adjoint of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I'm looking for a commutative diagram explaining the relationship between a vector space, $X$ the dual space, $X^*$, the double dual, $X^{**}$. I'm also looking for a diagram explaining the relationship between a linear map $T : X \longrightarrow Y$, $T^{\dagger}$ and $T^{\dagger \dagger }$. Ideally, I would like all of these ideas explained in a single diagram, but I haven't been able to come up with one on my own.

Comment: "all these ideas explained in a single diagram" seems a bit ambitious to me...